# A question about a coincidence by multiple solutions

Tags: geometry

I am solving a geometry problem as below
[image]

I would like to find the value of $A'CA$.
I came up with three constructions, but they seem to be in short of one condition, namely:

---

1. Construct $CD$ such that $CD\parallel AA'$
   [image]
   But this doesn't show that $A'B\parallel AC$
2. Reflect $\triangle A'AB$, but that doesn't show that $B'C$ is a straight line
   [image]
3. Construct $BD$ such that $BD\parallel A'A$, but that doesn't show that $A'B\parallel AC$ as well.
   [image]

---

Can these constructions find the answer or there exists some restrictions and is this a coincidence?

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "solutions" but "constructions".

Comment: Your constructions are short of one condition because I think you stopped too early. Unless there is some magic construction with just one or two lines, I think it requires you to draw some more lines and angles carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Draw $BD \parallel A'A$. Then you can easily show that,

$AB = A'B = BD = CD$ and $\angle BAD = 70^\circ$

Now draw $BE$ and $AE$ such that $\angle BAE = \angle ABE = 60^\circ$. So, $BE = BD = CD$.

As $DE$ bisects $BC$ and $BC$ bisects $\angle DBE$, we have $CE = CD = AE$.

Finally, $\angle ACE = 40^\circ \implies \angle A'CA = 20^\circ$.